# Qt Apple Push Notifications

Tags: ios, qt, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to register for Apple's Push Notification Service when developing an app using Qt 5.2 (http://qt-project.org/)?

I have experience of doing it with XCode and Objective-C, but can't find any help for doing the same with Qt.

Thanks

Comment: hi, have you resolved this problem, I encountered the same issue with you, could you give me some advice? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, when you build for iOS, it creates an XCode project in the build directory, I've had to just edit that project and put the push notification code in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: Do what you're doing, don't worry about Qt.

Qt does not provide any APIs targeted for that. There's no reason whatsoever not to keep using the Objective C/C++ code that you have. Simply add your `.m` and `.mm` files to `OBJECTIVE_SOURCES` in the .pro file.

Qt interoperates with Cocoa quite nicely; all threads with an event loop also spin a `NSRunLoop`, so notifications work as expected. `QString` has conversion methods to and from `NSString`.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer lead me to this tutorial http://el-tramo.be/blog/mixing-cocoa-and-qt/

Comment: I have read some iOS push notification documentation, it says that we should write some code in iOS Application class, but how can I do this with Qt?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for local push notifications you might also be interested in our Qt plugin at: http://plugins.v-play.net (I'm one of the authors behind V-Play Qt 5 Plugins).

We are currently also working on a plugin for Parse Push Notifications (from Facebook), which provide a nice interface for sending cross-platform pushs from the web and over an API.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample project which demonstrates how to implement iOs push notifications with Qt: https://github.com/gympulsr/qt-pushnotifications